# @font-face in Customize Control

Tags: theme-customizer, fonts

I've extended the `WP_Customize_Control` for displaying a `<select>` dropdown for fonts available in my theme (downloaded from Google Fonts and provided locally for privacy reasons). In order to make it easier to select a font, I want to show each font's name using the corresponding font-face.

Unfortunately, while all fonts are working in the preview, only locally installed fonts are applied in the `<select>`:

[image: Current customizer dropdown with only locally installed fonts being applied]

<sup>**Source Sans Pro** and **Roboto** are installed on the device and displayed correctly. **Roboto Mono** & **Montserrat** fall back to Times New Roman.</sup>

---

The `<option>` tags are created with inline styles assigning the font-family:

```php
foreach ($this->choices as $value => $label) {
    echo '<option […] style="font-family:' . $value . '">' . $label . '</option>';
}
```

The @font-faces are defined in my main css file & enqueued using the action `customize_controls_enqueue_scripts`. The fonts are working on the website & customizer preview and the stylesheet is loaded & applied in the customizer sidebar.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('../../fonts/source-sans-pro-v13-latin-regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local('Source Sans Pro Regular'), local('SourceSansPro-Regular'),
       url('../../fonts/source-sans-pro-v13-latin-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../../fonts/source-sans-pro-v13-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../../fonts/source-sans-pro-v13-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('../../fonts/source-sans-pro-v13-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../../fonts/source-sans-pro-v13-latin-regular.svg#SourceSansPro') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

When I select a font that is not installed locally, the browser downloads the font and applies it in the page preview, but no fonts are displayed in the `<select>` dropdown.

How can I load & display fonts in the Customizer sidebar?

Comment: You would need to load all fonts all times regardless of which one is selected to be able to show them all in the dropdown

Comment: @TomJNowell I might have phrased it in an unclear way: The selected font does not influence the customizer sidebar, only the website preview where everything loads correctly. If your advice still applies: how would I load all fonts at all times? Enqueue JS or some script in the customizer/control?

Comment: Even if you specify a tag for every font and tell the browser to use that font to render the option, the browser needs every single font loaded to display every single option in their fonts, and it needs loading in the customizer control to show it in the customizer control, not the preview iframe. Afterall if you don't have Roboto installed locally, how would the browser know how to render the Roboto option? The preview in the iframe knows because you told it to load that font from Google fonts

Comment: I just found out that this is a Firefox issue. Chrome and IE fully support font-family in <option>-tags, while Firefox seems to only partially support it. Meh.